# download doesn't work in firefox & IE & Edge (extension problem)

Tags: javascript, angular

I have some JavaScript code as given under first code snippet, that works in latest Chrome but not in latest FireFox. This code is exporting data to html file using Blob object. The strange thing is that in FireFox, the code does not throw any error but does get a file without extension.
same problem in Edge & IE

Code for exporting:

```
downloadFile(data: Response | any, fileName: string, typefile) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: typefile});
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const anchor = document.createElement('a');
      anchor.download = fileName;
      anchor.href = url;
      document.body.appendChild(anchor);
      anchor.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(`click`, {bubbles: true, cancelable: 
true, view: window}));
      document.body.removeChild(anchor);
      setTimeout(function() {window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url); }, 0);

    }
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  How do you know the problem is in this segment of code?

Comment: i just assumed it

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following code and tested in Edge and Firefox and it's working, also in Safari ( except Safari on Ipad)

```
   if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data, filename);
            }
            else {
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
                a.href = url;
                a.download = filename;
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                a.remove();
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.

Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

- BROWSER POLYFILLS *

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/

Please add below code in polyfills.ts

import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

Comment: I added it but same problem